# Cylindrical Coordinates with NDSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, coordinate-transformation

Can anyone help me figure out how to set up a solution for NDSolveValue that incorporates the use of Cylindrical Coordinates. I tried using SetCoordinates[Cylindrical] but it is not working (as in it wont recognize SetCoordinates). I am using version 10.2 so the VectorAnalysis functionality should be included. I am confused as to why it is not working.

**edit**: adding code

```
op = ρ c D[T[t, r, z], t] - k/r D[r D[T[t, r, z], r], r] - k D[D[T[t, r, z], z], z] - g; 

Subscript[Γ, D] = {DirichletCondition[T[t, r, z] == Tbl, 
      z == ts + tito + tsl && -reff < r < reff], 
      DirichletCondition[T[t, r, z] == BCr[z], r == -reff && r == reff]};
Subscript[Γ, N] = NeumannValue[0, z == 0 && -reff <= r <= reff];

td = 100;

Temp = NDSolveValue[{op == Subscript[Γ, N], Subscript[Γ, D], 
         T[0, r, z] == ?? }, T, {t, 0, td}, {r, z} ∈ mesh];
```

**edit #2**: adding more code (defining variables and calculating initial temperature profile)

```
reff = .001; ts = .000250; tito = .000005; tsl = .00023;

bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> {{-reff, 0}, {reff, 0}, {reff, ts}, {reff, 
      ts + tito}, {reff, ts + tito + tsl}, {-reff, 
      ts + tito + tsl}, {-reff, ts + tito}, {-reff, ts}}, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 
        5}, {5, 6}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}, {8, 1}, {8, 3}, {7, 4}}]}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh];
bmesh["Wireframe"]
mesh["Wireframe"]

ρs = 3980; ρito = 7120; ρsl = 958;
ks = .035; kito = .011; ksl = .00067;
cs = .75; cito = .25; csl = 4.22;
gs = 0; gito = 2800000; gsl = 0;

ρ = If[0 <= z < ts, ρs, 
   If[ts <= z < ts + tito, ρito, ρsl]];
k =  If[0 <= z < ts, ks, If[ts <= z < ts + tito, kito, ksl]];
c =  If[0 <= z < ts, cs, If[ts <= z < ts + tito, cito, csl]];
g =  If[0 <= z < ts, gs, If[ts <= z < ts + tito, gito, gsl]];

eqn1[z_] = k D[T1[z], z, z] + g; 

Tbl = 100;
Tl[z_] = Tbl;
Subscript[Γ1, D] = 
  DirichletCondition[T1[z] == Tbl, z == ts + tito + tsl];
Subscript[Γ1, N] = NeumannValue[0, z == 0];

BCr = NDSolveValue[{eqn1[z] == Subscript[Γ1, N], 
    Subscript[Γ1, D]}, T1, {z, 0, ts + tito + tsl}, 
   MaxStepSize -> 0.0000000001];

Plot[{BCr[z], VerticalSlider}, {z, 0, ts + tito + tsl}]
BCr[0]
BCr[ts]
BCr[ts + tito]
BCr[ts + tito + tsl]
Plot[BCr[z], {z, ts, ts + tito + tsl}]
Plot[BCr[z], {z, 0, ts}]
Plot[BCr[z], {z, ts, ts + tito}]
Plot[BCr[z], {z, ts + tito, ts + tito + tsl}]
Plot[BCr[z], {z, ts - tito, ts + tito}]
Plot[BCr[z], {z, ts - 2*tito, ts + 3*tito}]
Plot[BCr[z], {z, ts + tito, ts + 3*tito}]
Ti[z_] := Piecewise[{{BCr[z], 0 <= z < ts + tito}, {100, True}}];
Plot[Ti[z], {z, 0, ts + tito + tsl}]
```

Comment: Please provide more information.  For instance, what equations are you trying to integrate, and what are the boundary conditions?  Express these in Mathematica format, if possible.

Comment: I am trying to solve the heat equation in cylindrical coordinates . I want to solve it for radial boundary conditions where temperature is constant with time and axial boundary conditions that are constant Temperature on one side and constant heat flux on the other side. There are two separate mediums involved to simulate a heated wall condition. Initial conditions include a linear temperature profile in the solid and a constant temperature in the fluid. It is initially discontinuous (fluid temperature not equal to solid wall). Assume no relative motion of the fluid (no convective term).

Comment: I added the code in the original post as it would not fit in the comment

Comment: Putting your code in the question was the right thing to do.  I have improved the appearance of the code a bit but not changed it substantively.  To proceed, replace `??` by the desired initial condition, replace `{r, z} ∈ mesh` by `{r, -reff, reff}, {z, 0, zmax}`, and define the constants that appear in  your code.  Your challenge here is not cylindrical coordinates per se (although negative `r` is an issue) but in producing self-consistent code.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the ??. The initial condition is being set equal to a discontinuous temperature profile. I will post the code that sets the initial temperature profile as well as defining the variables in the edited post.

Comment: Forgot to mention the initial conditions ?? should be replaced by Ti[z_] (and constant with respect to r)

Comment: Please learn more about how to [format your code](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) so your question may attract more attention, also, you may want to know [how to use @](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/284701).

Comment: @xzczd - thank you for your help with the formatting! I will make sure to do so in the future.

Comment: To be honest, your question still looks frustrating, you'd better simplify your code sample as much as possible, currently your sample contains many irrelevant part (I mean the `Plot`, `BCr[…]`, etc., which can just be deleted) and a lot of tedious but not-that-important coefficients (I mean the `ρs` etc., why not replacing them with some simple number?).

Comment: I don't have much time today but I will try to simply the code and re-post.  The constants are important because they are material properties for an actual system. This code is modeling an experimental setup to try and replicate the temperature response analytically. I could change them for simplification of the problem but eventually they will be important. As of now I can obtain a somewhat accurate steady state solution which is what is being plotted.